# Clarification on statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance

> “The variation achieved a 20% increase in conversions with 90%
>   significance.” Unfortunately, this isn’t equivalent to, “there is a
>   90% chance of a 20% increase.” So what does it actually mean?
>
> 20% is the increase we observed in our sample, and, if we had to
>   guess, it’s the increase we’d expect to see if we continued the test
>   indefinitely. It’s the most likely outcome. But there is not a 90%
>   chance of a 20% increase, or even a 90% chance of an increase of at
>   least 20% or approximately 20%.
>
> 90% is the chance that there would be a difference at all. In other
>   words, if we had ten tests producing this result, and we decided to
>   continue all ten tests indefinitely, we’d expect one to end up with
>   the original and variation converging to identical conversion rates.
>   Of the remaining nine tests, some might end up showing an increase of
>   far less than 20%. Others might end up showing an even bigger
>   increase.

I somehow feel that the 2nd paragraph is a poor explanation or maybe even wrong.
The way I look at it, in simple words, it means there is only a 10% probability that the 20% variation was due to chance.

[Original Link here](https://www.distilled.net/resources/statistical-significance-for-cro-6-things-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: (+1) Very closely related--it probably already has some good answers--is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the-mean. The third paragraph is amazingly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the second paragraph is wrong.

Probably a better way to rephrase the initial sentence would be: "The variation achieved a 20% increase in conversions. This increase was significant at the 0.1 level."

This means that if there was no real difference at all (increase = 0%), you would still expect 10% of the times you repeat your sample to get an increase at least as large as that 20% by chance.