# Producing error bars and confidence intervals when dealing with asymmetrical probability density functions

Tags: confidence-interval, error

When we define confidence intervals or error bars, as I understand it, we usually deal with the standard deviation when it comes to Gaussian statistics. That is to say, $68.27\%$ of the data will lie within $\pm \sigma$ around the mean (in the Gaussian case also the median).

Unless I am mistaken, one can use the standard deviation as a metric to define confidence intervals or error bars on data. I.e. $1\sigma = 68.27\%$, $2\sigma = 95.45\%$, and so on. Defining confidence intervals or error bars in this way is especially useful when weighting data, which as I understand it for Gaussian statistics is $1/\sigma^{2}$.

My questions are if we are dealing with non-Gaussian, asymmetric probability density functions -- for example the Rayleigh distribution $$R(\sigma, x) = \frac{x}{\sigma^{2}}e^{-x^{2}/(2\sigma^{2})}$$ 
**How do we define a confidence interval, or something analogous to the standard deviation for non-Gaussian distributions?**

My first thought is that we must determine the mean, or expected value of the distribution and we can do that by $$\mu = E(x) = \int x f(x) \ dx$$ -- $f(x)$ being the distribution we are interested in. In the case of the Rayleigh distribution this comes out as $$\mu = \sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}$$.

[image]

Here the shape parameter, $\sigma$ is shown in blue and the mean as described above in red.

Given that I am interested in looking for something some what similar to a standard deviation for use as an error bar or a confidence interval, and given that the distribution is asymmetric, I would also expect the error bar to interval to be asymmetric i.e. $$x^{\sigma_{+}}_{\sigma_{-}}$$

I would determine $\sigma_{+}$ and $\sigma_{-}$ by first defining a proportion of data I want to find e.g. $0.6827$ and then perform the following inetgrations
$$\int_{\sigma_{-}}^{\sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}} R(\sigma, x) \ dx = \frac{0.6827}{2}$$
$$\int_{\sigma \sqrt{\pi/2}}^{\sigma_{+}} R(\sigma, x) \ dx = \frac{0.6827}{2}$$
Solving both for $\sigma_-$ and $\sigma_+$ gives the error bar or confidence interval.

### First Question:

Is the approach I have described above reasonable?
If not, what should I look at?

### Second Question:

How does one apply weights when dealing with non-Gaussian statistics? Clearly if one has an asymmetric error bar $1/\sigma^{2}$ will not work.

---

I clearly have misunderstood the difference between an error bar and a confidence interval -- there is a very good explanation given in one of the comments to this question -- thanks very much to this user!

I think perhaps a better question is then:

Given I understand the distribution from which my data is drawn, what is the best approach of generating a confidence interval for use in fitting and extracting unobserved parameters. For example if I have a function which could be noised additively or multiplicatively, for example 
$$f(t) = A \sin(\omega t) + \xi(t)$$
or
$$f(t) = A \sin(\omega t) \xi(t)$$
where $\xi(t)$ is drawn from some non-Gaussian distribution. If I then have knowledge of the distribution from which $\xi(t)$ is drawn, is it possible (or even necessary) to generate a confidence interval for this data set for use in fitting, to act as a weight?

Or is a confidence interval only useful for giving information about the fit itself?

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to indicate some confusion about a confidence interval (CI) and error bars, as commonly understood. A 95% CI does *not* contain 95% of the data. [It is an algorithm that, if repeated many times, will contain *the parameter of interest* 95% of times.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217377/1352) It is not a data quantile. Thus, if your mean is normally distributed (cf. the CLT), a normal-based symmetric CI makes sense even if your data are non-normal. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica Thanks for that clarification! I will add some further detail in my question based on your comments.

Comment: @S.Kolassa-ReinstateMonica I have added a short paragraph, clarifying based on the additional information you gave me.

Comment: Note that confidence intervals are for parameters. You seek to be after some other sort of interval, such as a tolerance interval or a prediction interval. It might be worth seeing other posts on site with those terms, or indeed relevant wikipedia pages

Comment: Further if you want "something like an error bar", the difficulty is that there are multiple kinds, so you need to explain clearly what it does - what it represents, what properties it should have. I am not confident I clearly understand what you need

Comment: I'm going to vote to close my question because I think I need to consider what I want a little more.