# How to find confidence interval of expected sample results from true population proportion?

Tags: confidence-interval, population

Let's say I know the true population proportion of a particular attribute, say 15% of people are left-handed. Imagine I perform a random sample of 1000 people around the world. How do I compute a 95% confidence interval of the number of people I expect to be left-handed from this sample?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  This isn't a [confidence interval:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450) it's a calculation of percentiles of the sampling distribution, which is *Binomial:* that word makes a good search term.

Comment: @whuber This makes sense, but when I look up binomial sampling, all the answers/examples assume that I want to calculate the true population proportion based on a sample proportion. But I want the opposite, and I can't seem to find anything on that. Can you direct me toward something that could help clear up my confusion?

Comment: Outline: Using the normal approximation to a binomial distribution you seek $P(L \le X \le U) \approx P[(L-\mu)/\sigma < Z < (U-\mu)/\sigma)=.95,$ where $X \sim BINOM(n,p)$ and $Z$ is standard normal. So $(U - \mu)/\sigma) \approx 1.96.$ Evaluate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and solve for $L$ and $U.$ // In my answer I show how to get L and U using R statistical software.

Answer (score 3):

**Exact binomial computation.** If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=1000, p=0.15),$ then
$P(128 \le X \le 172) = 0.954,$ according to exact
computations using R statistical software.
[In R `qbinom` the inverse of a binomial CDF, and `dbinom` is a binomial PDF.]

```
qbinom(c(.025,.975), 1000, .15)
[1] 128 172
sum(dbinom(128:172, 1000, .15))
[1] 0.9538581
```

If this is from a problem in an elementary statistics
or probability class that is not using software, then
you may be expected to get a good approximate value
by using the fact that the distribution of $X$
is approximately $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = np, \sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}),$ where $n = 1000, p = 0.15.$
You could use either software or printed tables of
the standard normal CDF for that computation.

One method using R is shown below. The area under
the density curve of $\mathsf{Norm}(150, 11.29)$
between 127.5 and 172.5 is about 0.954. So the normal
approximation method gives essentially the same integer
boundaries.

```
n = 1000;  p = .15
mu = n*p;  sg = sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
mu;  sg
[1] 150
[1] 11.29159
qnorm(c(.025,.975), mu, sg)
[1] 127.8689 172.1311
diff(pnorm(c(127.5,172.5), mu, sg))
[1] 0.9536984
```

The following figure shows the binomial distribution (blue histogram) and the approximating normal density curve (black curve).

[image]