# Are CI and hypothesis tests purely frequentist tools?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, frequentist

I've been learning statistics for a long time but I still struggle to understand the "philosophical" differences between frequentist and bayesian statistics. One of my questions is the following:

Are confidence intervals and hypothesis tests purely frequentist devices? (Since their motivation is to bound our search for the "true" population parameters).

P.S.: This question was associated with a different one before, but the other question does not answer my question.

Comment: Bayesians have (null) hypothesis tests as well - Bayesians can even evaluate the posterior probability of a hypothesis, so they are arguably more directly interpretable.  Confidence intervals do not bound our search for the "true" population parameters, but Bayesian credible intervals do. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the/26457#26457  AFAICS there is no reason why a Bayesian cannot construct a Bayesian confidence interval, it is just a different question.

Comment: Does this mean that bayesians also try to infer values about an "unknown probability distribution with defined parameters"? I struggle to understand the concept of credible intervals without a reference to a "true" population distribution.

Comment: Yes, A Bayesian may attempt to infer e.g. the mean and variance of a Gaussian from a sample of data from that distribution.  The credible interval for the mean would be an interval that contains the true mean with probability $p$, so it is directly linked to the "true" population.  Note a frequentist confidence interval does not contain the true value with probability $p$, it is a statement of what would happen if you resampled the data and repeated the experiment, so it IMHO is less directly related to the population distribution.